# Cookies created by Javascript not seen by C# (ASP.NET Razor)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, cookies

I'm setting a cookie in Javascript:

```
document.cookie = "lang=" + lang + ";path=/;domain=" + window.location.hostname + ";";
```

If I check the cookies in the browser, I can see this one. But when I run :

```
@if (Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("lang")) {
    @Response.Cookies["lang"].Value;
}
```

I get no output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Response.Cookies
```

should be

```
Request.Cookies
```

**Request.Cookies** cookies come from client (browser) to the server and **Response.Cookies** cookies are sent back to the client (browser) from the server.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of the difference!